# R ggplot2: Adding a Legend to a Time Series with Forecasts

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I've been looking at this for hours stumped. I've come across a number of suggestions that I need to add aes() and assigning colours to the geom_lines but this isn't generating anything - potentially as I have some forecasts in as well? I'm really not too sure.

In any case I've put my code below, and really appreciate any help that can be provided.

```
install.packages("fpp")
library(fpp)
data("books")
library(ggplot2)
paperback <- books[,1]
fit1    <-  ses(paperback,  alpha   =   0.2,    initial =   "simple",   h   =   3)
fit2    <-  ses(paperback,  alpha   =   0.6,    initial =   "simple",   h   =   3)
fit3    <-  ses(paperback,  h   =   3)

autoplot(paperback,
     xlab="Day",    main="", size = 20) + 
     geom_line(data = paperback, colour = "black", aes(colour="black")) + 
     geom_line(data = fitted(fit1), colour = "blue", linetype = 2, aes(colour="blue")) + 
     geom_line(data = fitted(fit2), colour = "red", linetype = 2, aes(colour="red")) + 
     geom_line(data = fitted(fit3), colour = "green", linetype = 2, aes(colour = "green")) + 
     geom_line(data = fit1$mean, colour = "blue", linetype = 2) + 
     geom_line(data = fit2$mean, colour = "red", linetype = 2) + 
     geom_line(data = fit3$mean, colour = "green", linetype = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to plot directly the forecast objects:

```
install.packages("fpp")
require("fpp"); require("books"); require("ggplot2"); require("ggfortify")
data("books")

paperback <- books[,1]

fit1    <-  ses(paperback,  alpha   =   0.2,    initial =   "simple",   h   =   3)
fit2    <-  ses(paperback,  alpha   =   0.6,    initial =   "simple",   h   =   3)
fit3    <-  ses(paperback,  h   =   3)

par(mfrow = c(1,3))
plot(fit1)
plot(fit2)
plot(fit3)
```

and this produces:

[image]

and if you want to do it with ggplot you can do:

```
X <- cbind(model1 = fit1$mean, model2 = fit2$mean, model3 = fit3$mean)
df <- cbind(paperback, X)
colnames(df) <- c("paperback", "model1", "model2", "model3")
autoplot(df)
```

produces:

[image]